# How to use groupby? using groupby to find odd or even number by getting inputs from a function

Tags: python, python-itertools

Below is my task

1. Define a function even_or_odd, which takes an integer as input and returns the string even and odd, if the given number is even and odd respectively.
2. Categorise the numbers of list n = [10, 14, 16, 22, 9, 3 , 37] into two groups namely even and odd based on above defined function.
   Hint : Use groupby method of itertools module.
3. Iterate over the obtained groupby object and print it's group name and list of elements associated with a group.

**I have written the below code** : I am getting the error 'str' object is not callable. Actually I am not sure how to use itertool groupby() by getting values from a function. Can someone guide me ?

```
from itertools import groupby

def even_or_odd(r):
    for i in r:
        if i%2 == 0:
            return "even"
        else:
            return "odd"


n = [10, 14, 16, 22, 9, 3 , 37]


for key, group in groupby(n, even_or_odd(n)):
    if key == even:
        print(key, list(group))
    else:
        print(key, list(group))
```

Answer (score 0):

here the solution
according to the doc https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

`The key is a function computing a key value for each element`

```
from itertools import groupby

n = [10, 14, 16, 22, 9, 3 , 37]

def even_or_odd(val):
     if val%2 == 0:
       return "even"
     else:  
       return "odd"


for key, group in groupby(n, even_or_odd):
    print(key, list(group))
```

output :

```
even [10, 14, 16, 22]
odd [9, 3, 37]
```

Comment: Thanks Beny, so group by will pass each element separately. 
Also how it is displaying even adn odd values separately by correctly identify the key.